# Querying the size of a column family in RocksDB

Tags: rocksdb, column-family

Is there a way to know the size of all KVs that are stored in a column family?

Answer (score 1):

1. For API you can use: [`GetApproximateSizes()`](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/be219089ad280a8317086b428615c0a1c965eeff/include/rocksdb/db.h#L1045-L1055).
2. If you just want to check, you can check RocksDB log, which has per column family `Compaction Stats`, which SST file size for each level.
3. It's not reporting column family size, but if you're interested in bytes written, there's a statistic reporting that: [`rocksdb.bytes.written`](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/e817bc9628aec29b19e7b75a672e8bb6fbea349b/monitoring/statistics.cc#L65), you can get statistic by setting [`statistics`](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/f127d459adddd4d1e381541ac066610df6905f8a/include/rocksdb/options.h#L530-L531), like:

```
options.statistics = CreateDBStatistics()
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use `GetApproximateSizes()?` Specifically, if I want the size of the *entire* column, what do I use as a `Range`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the total size of all SST files under a column family, a better way is via [GetIntProperty()](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/2e5f76429402f674b111821517e1382760e3cfd/include/rocksdb/db.h#L1057-L1058).  In your case, you want to pass-in [kTotalSstFileSize](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/2e5f76429402f674b111821517e1382760e3cfd/include/rocksdb/db.h#L917).

bool ok = db_->GetIntProperty(DB::Properties::kTotalSstFilesSize, &sst_size);

If you only care about the latest version of the SST files, then you should use [kTotalLiveSstFileSize](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/2e5f76429402f674b111821517e1382760e3cfd/include/rocksdb/db.h#L919-L921) instead.

Comment: But how would this compare to `GetApproximateSizes` in terms of performance? Because with `GetApproximateSizes` you can decrease precision for a better performance, right?